In carrying out a post test after identifying an AR model, how do I know when to use an ARMA or ARIMA before estimation of variables
After identifying my AR model,how do I know based on my data if an ARMA or ARIMA should be applied using an Eviews 12 software? Aside the fact that an acf or pacf may be undertaken prior to my estimation of variables

I don't quite understand what you are looking for. If you have already identified your AR model (and thus presumably ruled out other ARIMA models), why would you afterwards want to decide once more on whether to use ARMA or ARIMA? Or are you asking how to decide in the first place? Standard software like the forecast or fable package in R use unit roots for this step. I don't know how Eviews deals with this, but doesn't it have an auto-ARIMA feature?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
